# R Studio will not open .r files in source

Tags: r, rstudio, rscript

I have used R for years and, until recently, have had few problems.  However, since the last update, R keeps erasing scripts that I have saved in the Source window; then, when I go to retrieve them from recent files, it opens a script that has a title but zero code.  I am able to open the files in notepad and copy/paste them back in, but I would like to know how to resolve this issue so that I could use R in the same expeditious manner as previous.

To reiterate with slightly different wording: R opens my saved scripts (.r files) as codeless source windows; there is simply a number 1 there and nothing else, though the title is displayed.  I did save one as a text file and tried to open it that way but got the same results.  Opening files in Notepad and copying/pasting them does work, but obviously R should be able to open R scripts and display R code.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Thank you,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

It's not sophisticated, but I would

1. uninstall R & RStudio
2. reset/remove the "internal state" stored by RStudio
3. reset/remove the "preferences" stored by RStudio
4. reinstall R & RStudio

Here's good documentation from RStudio for points 2 & 3, depending on your version and OS: https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State